# Limit RemoveAll to a certain number of objects

Tags: c#, lambda, removeall

I am working with a `List<T>` which contains both parent and children objects. In this list children objects are aware of their related parent object and vice versa. Using this list I am trying to implement a business rule where up to 4 children objects will be removed from the list when their parent is of a certain type. Put differently if a parent of this type has 20 children 4 of them should be removed from the list.

The code I have outlined here will `RemoveAll` of the children objects that meet the condition. This is expected but what I'd like to do is limit the `RemoveAll` to removing only 4 children. Is there a means to do this with `RemoveAll` or is there another method I should be using?

```
myList.RemoveaAll(item =>
  item.Child && "Foo".Equals(item.Parent.SpecialType));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Take** extension method is used to grab the first n number of matches from an IEnumerable.  You can then iterate through the matches and remove them from the list.

```
var matches = myList.Where(item => item.Child && "Foo".Equals(item.Parent.SpecialType)).Take(someNumber).ToList();
matches.ForEach(m => myList.Remove(m));
```

Comment: To clarify, Take does not remove any items. You are using it to find the items which you subsequently wish to remove.

Comment: There's only one problem: `Take()` doesn't iterate the list. So with the code as-is, you are iterating over myList while removing from the list. THIS IS BAD! I suggest you append `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to your first line. In fact, I'll go ahead and add it for you, feel free to rollback if you disagree.

Comment: With @Randolpho's modification this works like a charm. Otherwise a .ToList had to be appended to matches before using `ForEach`. I had never seen the `Take` extension method. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @ashteel: adding `.ToList()` after the `Take()` call or appending it to `matches` accomplish the same thing; the only thing that changes is what the type of matches actually is in that short time. You could just as easily have done it in a single line: `myList.Where(item => item.Child && "Foo".Equals(item.Parent.SpecialType)).Take(someNumber).ToList().ForEach(m => myList.Remove(m));`

Answer (score 2):

Does it matter which 4? If not, you can use `.Take(4)` to create a list of 4 children, then iterate through and `Remove` the 4...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int i = 0;
myList.Removeall(item =>
  item.Child && "Foo".Equals(item.Parent.SpecialType) && i++ < 4);
```

Note that I haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: Without testing this does `i` get reset to 0 upon each iteration? It seems like it would work for the first find but wouldn't afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `Take` function?

Comment: Take does not modify the list. He wants to remove items.

Comment: Take does not modify the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write an extension method to build on top of the normal list interface like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace App
{

    public static class ListExtension
    {
        public static int RemoveAll<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> match, uint maxcount)
        {
            uint removed = 0;
            Predicate<T> wrappingmatcher = (item) =>
            {
                if (match(item) && removed < maxcount)
                {
                    removed++;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            return list.RemoveAll(wrappingmatcher);
        }
    }

    public interface IHero { }
    public class Batman : IHero { }

    public class HeroCompilation
    {
        public List<IHero> Herolist;

        public HeroCompilation()
        {
            Herolist = new List<IHero>();
        }

        public void AddBatmans(int count){
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) Herolist.Add(new Batman());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void ConsoleWriteBatmanCount(List<IHero> hero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Batmans", hero.Count);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HeroCompilation tester = new HeroCompilation();
            ConsoleWriteBatmanCount(tester.Herolist);
            tester.AddBatmans(10);
            ConsoleWriteBatmanCount(tester.Herolist);
            tester.Herolist.RemoveAll((x) => { return true; }, 4);
            ConsoleWriteBatmanCount(tester.Herolist);
            tester.Herolist.RemoveAll((x) => { return true; }, 4);
            ConsoleWriteBatmanCount(tester.Herolist);
            tester.Herolist.RemoveAll((x) => { return true; }, 4);
            ConsoleWriteBatmanCount(tester.Herolist);
            while (true) ;
        }
    }
}
```